# Hang on welcome screen for many hours due to 0 space in drive C

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My server 2008r2 hang on welcome screen for many hours due to 0 space in drive C. so how can i login to free some space from C drive. please help to find out its solution

Comment: Boot off of a live CD or other rescue media, mount the filesystem, delete things that you don't need.

Comment: If the server is available on the network, browse to \\server\C$\ from another machine. This will prompt for admin credentials.

Comment: #Cory Knutson, server is on network and but this command is working Error "window can'nt access check speliing of name etc"

Comment: #Cory Knutson, its working i used ip add of server instead of name. Bundle of thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot into "Safe mode with command prompt" (press `F8` at boot time). From here, you should be able to delete unneeded files.

If you have problems even in safe mode, use a Linux Live CD to mount the NTFS filesystem and free some space.